# How to create checkboxes using scaffold in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, scaffolding

I have to create a feature to manage my contracts. Everything was going fine working with the strings etc.. but I have to create checkboxes in my scaffold for an example 
()Toll 
()Chemist 
And I want to save this if the boxes are checked.
I tried put this code into the Form file, it appears, but don't save the data when checked, I guess that is not the correct way, because there is nothing created in the database.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="tag_ids[]" value="1" />
```

I'm planning to generate all the checkboxes as strings when generating the scaffold and try something else. 
Does anyone have a better idea how can I accomplish this, could be the easiest way as possible is not for real development. Thanks for all.

Comment: What is the name of model for which you are trying to save the value?

Answer (score 0):

first you should check if the vars are whitelisted,
second you should try the rails helper for this:

```
<%= form.check_box "tag_ids[]", "Chemist", false, id:"1"%>
```

with this syntax the input will be stored in an array, so you can add multiple checkboxes for the same variable. the input will than be stored `["Chemist","Toll"]`

Later you can split these easily by `.split`

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following to your form

```
<% Tag.all.each do |tag| %>
  <label>
    <%= f.check_box_tag "contract[tag_ids][]", tag.id, @contract.tags.include?(tag) %>
    <%= tag.name %>
  </label>
<% end %>
```

This can then be passed through your parameters as long as your strong parameters allow them eg:

```
params.require(:contract).permit(.... ,  tag_ids: [])
```

see here for a proper discussion: https://kolosek.com/rails-join-table/

Also if you are interested I'd look at using simple_form (https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) for your rails forms.  It makes all of this really easy.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you reply but I'm having the following error: "uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::Tag"

Comment: The above answer assumes there is a model Tag containing all your tags.